# How to get all shipping method collection for admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

How to get all shipping method label in  Custom Grid admin module . I am using the below Code .Its returning all shipping method Lable But i need all those as a collection . So i can use it my Custom admin grid .Can Any One Help us out

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$shipMethods = array();
foreach ($methods as $shippigCode=>$shippingModel) 
{
    $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/title');
    $shipMethods[$shippigCode] = $shippingTitle;
}
return $shipMethods;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your example, the shipping title may or may not be derived from the database. Thus, the collection cannot be created directly. It should still be possible to create your collection afterwards – once you have all necessary data at hand:

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

$shipMethodCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
foreach ($methods as $shippingCode => $shippingModel)
{
    $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippingCode.'/title');
    $shipMethod = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code' => $shippingCode,
        'title' => $shippingTitle,
    ));
    $shipMethodCollection->addItem($shipMethod);
}
return $shipMethodCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Shipping_Allmethods`